# Reference Cells in Sorted Filter View

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that looks like this:

[image: 01]

That Google Sheet has some Google Script that looks like Google This:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = ss.getActiveCell();
  Logger.log("Range " + rng.getA1Notation() + " value = " + rng.getValue());
}
```

When I run that script with the sheet as seen above, the log has this text:

```
Range C3 value = Charlie's Horses
```

That's as expected. Now, I add a Filter View to the sheet so it looks like this:

[image: 02]

When I run the code again, I get the same output:

```
Range C3 value = Charlie's Horses
```

However, when I *sort* that filter view, things go haywire.

[image: 03]

I've sorted by column A descending but I still have "Charlie's Horses" selected. When I run the script, though, the logger has an unexpected output:

```
Range C9 value = Eye Doctor
```

It has the expected range address of `C9` but the value is not what I'm seeing. As far as I can tell, that's because `.getValue()` is pulling the data from the original, unfiltered view of the sheet.

---

**Is there any way in Google Sheets / GAS to reference cells in a sorted filter view rather than the data in the unfiltered view?**

The script that raised this issue needs to collect the values for cells on the same row in column A and C as well as getting / updating the comment on the cell in column C. If I'm able to reference the correct range object, I could work it out from there.

Comment: As far as I know, Google Apps Script and filter/filter views live in parallel universes, not being aware of each other.

Answer (score 1):

On April 11, 2018 Google added new classes to handle filter but not for handling filtered views.

The alternatives are

- do the filtering on the script side and for that use the array handling features of JavaScript
- use the Google Sheets Advanced Service.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/
- [Using Google Sheets filters in Add-ons with Google Apps Script](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/using-google-sheets-filters-in-add-ons.html)

Comment: I follow a thread on the support forums that keyed me in to the new classes. However, my specific issue is to get a value from a different cell in the same row as the current selection. From my testing, the update doesn't address that because nothing captures the sort order of the current view.

Comment: @EngineerToast That was I mean by "not for handling filtered views"